# How to use paginate and findwhere at the same? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, repository, laravel-5.3

I using third party. I get from here : https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

My function in file repository is like this :

```
public function displayList($year, $id = NULL)
{
    $clauses = ['year' => $year];
    if(isset($id)) {
        $clauses = array_merge($clauses, ['id' => $id]);
    }
    $query = Self::orderBy('programcode')
                 ->orderBy('accountcode')
                 ->findWhere($clauses)
                 ->paginate(1);
    return $query;
}
```

When executed, there exist error like this : `Method paginate does not exist.`.

I try remove `->findWhere($clauses)`. It works. No error.

Findwhere and paginate apparently can not run simultaneously

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because [`->findWhere(...)`](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Eloquent/BaseRepository.php#L385) ends the query [with `->get()`](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Eloquent/BaseRepository.php#LC400) and returns the results (eloquent collection).

What you're trying to do is calling a `->paginate(...)` method on an [eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections#available-methods). It is actually a method on [query builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_paginate).

**<s>Solution</s>**

[applyConditions](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository/blob/master/src/Prettus/Repository/Eloquent/BaseRepository.php#L822)

```
$query = Self::orderBy('programcode')
             ->orderBy('accountcode')
             ->applyConditions($clauses)
             ->paginate(1);
```

**Edit**

Okay, so `->applyCondtions()` does not return the object so you can't chain methods off of it. Try this:

```
$query = Self::orderBy('programcode')
    ->orderBy('accountcode');
$query->applyConditions($clauses);
$query = $query->paginate(1);
```

Comment: Continue what its solution? On documentation exist `->paginate(...)`. Look here : https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository

Comment: @mosestoh after digging around I'm pretty sure I found the solution. Updated the answer.

Comment: There exist error : `Call to a member function paginate() on null`

Comment: @mosestoh I've updated the answer, can you try the new way?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$list = $this->repository->scopeQuery(function($query) use ($filterColumns) {

    return $query->where($filterColumns)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

});

$list->paginate(10);
```